# How to override super interface @PreAuthorize expression

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a generic service with annotations, this is extended by every service interface. How can I override this annotation from the service interface?

I put the @PreAuthorize annotation on the service interface but it did not work, however, when I put this on the service implementation it did.

My generic service interface looks like this:

```java
public interface GenericService<T, ID> {
    @PreAuthorize(/*Generic condition*/)
    T get(ID id);
}
```

My entity's service interface (where I want this to work)

```java
public interface EntityService extends GenericService<Entity, Integer> {
    @PreAuthorize(/*Specific condition*/)
    Entity get(Integer id);
}
```

My entity's service implementation (where it does work)

```java
@Service
public class EntityServiceImpl extends AbstractServiceImpl<Entity, Integer> implements EntityService {
    @Override
    @PreAuthorize(/*Specific condition*/)
    public Entity get(Integer id) {
        return super.get(id);
    }
}
```

Slice of my abstract service implementation class:

```java
public abstract class AbstractServiceImpl<T extends AbstractEntity<ID>, ID> implements GenericService<T, ID> {
    @Override
    public T get(ID id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```

I don't want to put this on the implementation because this is not specific to it. It must be the same condition across every posible implementation of the service.

Comment: What happens when you call the get(id) method from the `EntityService` superclass from inside it's implementation? From my understanding, if you call the get method from `EntityServiceImpl` it should use its authorization criteria to allow/disallow it. If there is a super class method call from inside it, then the super class authorization criteria will come into play. Is this not the behavior seen there?

Comment: Indeed, test are passing. I put the annotation on the `EntityService` interface and overwrote the get(id) method on the `EntityServiceImpl` class just to call super.

Comment: Is this because the `EntityService` interface applies in the context of `EntityServiceImpl` and the `GenericService` interface applies in the context of the `AbstractServiceImpl` class?

Comment: Well, this is not the way it is working, it is just taking one condition **or** the another, not one **and** the another. But this is exactly what I need